# Reading JSON Object created from MVC View Model

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I am able to pass my Model to the view with the following Code in controller

```
Models.Models.AELeadInfo lead = new Models.Models.AELeadInfo();
lead.firstName = "name";
lead.lastName = "lastname";
lead.add1 = "add1";
lead.add2 = "add2";
lead.city = "city";
lead.state = "state";
lead.zip = "zip";
lead.birthDay = "bday";
lead.phone = "phone";
lead.email = "email";
lead.preferedContact = "prefContact";

//do DB stuff
// return model
return Json(lead, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

My Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    datatype: "json",
    url: "/Home/loadLeadInfo/",
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: { 'leadPhone': lph},
    success: function (data) {             
        $("#ld1_lastName").val( data.LastName);
        alert(data.LastName);
    },
});
```

I can see that everything is there when I hover over data in Chrome dev tools, but `data.lastName` returns undefined. I must be missing something simple here, been trying things and googling for hours with no luck.

Comment: Your code has an uppercase L in LastName, in the C# its a lower case l, case does matter, have you tried `data.lastName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer it as:

```
data.lastName
```

And not as:

`data.LastName`

After all, you declared it with a lower case `l` and not `L` and JavaScript is case-sensitive.